# How to tweak \volcite in biblatex-chicago to cite volume and page using Arabic numerals separated by a colon

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

Is there a simple way to change `biblatex-chicago`'s treatment of `\volcite` commands such that when citing a volume and page of a multi-volume book, it outputs "`[vol]`:`[page(s)]`" instead of "vol. `[vol]`, p./pp. `[page(s)]`"? (But when citing only the volume or volumes, but no page, I don't want it to change the output.)

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\volcite{1}[50]{knuth:ct}. \mancite

\volcite{1--2}{knuth:ct}.
\end{document}
```

I would like the output to be

> Donald E. Knuth, *Computers & Typesetting*, 5 vols. (Reading, Mass.: Addison- Wesley, 1984–1986), 1:50.
>
> Knuth, *Computers & Typesetting*, vols. 1–2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by redefining `\volcitedelim` and `\mkvolcitenote`.

The one caveat is that something like `\volcite{1}[a note]{knuth:ct}` will give slightly unexpected results. But is is easy enough to work around by putting non-page number postnotes outside the citation command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\volcitedelim}{\addcolon}

\renewrobustcmd*{\mkvolcitenote}[2]{%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {\printtext[volcitevolume]{#1}}
    {\printtext{#1}\volcitedelim\printtext{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\volcite{1}[50]{knuth:ct}. \mancite

\volcite{1--2}{knuth:ct}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. I noticed that the style guidelines I am looking at eliminate the comma after `shorthand`s in the case of a multivolume work, e.g., "*CCAG* 5:102" instead of "*CCAG*, 5:102". (But still keeping the comma in the case of a `shorthand` followed by just a page number.) Is there an extra line one could add for that functionality?

Comment: @AlexRoberts, this is probably worth a separate question. `biblatex-chicago` is not always easy to modify and you will get a better quality of answer if others see it too.

Comment: you're right, I should make it a separate question. I'll do that now.

Comment: The separate question about the comma is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472242/removing-comma-after-shorthands-in-biblatex-chicago).