# Removing comma after shorthands in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation, biblatex-chicago

This is a follow-up question to a previous question I asked about "[How to tweak volcite in biblatex-chicago to cite volume and page using Arabic numerals separated by a colon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472053/how-to-tweak-volcite-in-biblatex-chicago-to-cite-volume-and-page-using-arabic-n/472063#472063)".

I would like to know if there is any way (when using a colon to separate volume and page references, but only when both a volume and a page are given) to further instruct `biblatex-chicago` to omit the comma between citation and volume/page number when *both* of the following conditions apply:

1. a `shorthand` field is being used (i.e., the bib entry has a non-empty `shorthand` field AND `biblatex-chicago` has been set up to use shorthands AND the conditions are such that this particular citation will in fact be using that shorthand)
2. both a volume and a page are indicated in the cite command (e.g., `\volcite{5}[102]{CCAG:astrology}`)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{CCAG:astrology,
    Address = {Brussels},
    Date = {1898/1953},
    Editor = {Cumont, Franz},
    Title = {Catalogus codicum astrologorum graecorum},
    Shorthand = {\emph{CCAG}}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% VOLCITE USING COLON (solution by David Purton)
\renewcommand*{\volcitedelim}{\addcolon}
\renewrobustcmd*{\mkvolcitenote}[2]{%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {\printtext[volcitevolume]{#1}}
    {\printtext{#1}\volcitedelim\printtext{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\volcite{5}[102]{CCAG:astrology}.\mancite

\volcite{5}[102]{CCAG:astrology}.
\end{document}
```

I would like the output of the second paragraph to be

> *CCAG* 5:102.

instead of

> *CCAG*, 5:102.

but would like everything else to remain the same.

Comment: Do you need "ibid."? And if so should it always output "ibid., 5:102" even for shorthands?

Comment: :( I can't make it work for the multicite version (`\volcites`). But if an answer supporting just `\volcite` is acceptable, I think I can help.

Comment: @DavidPurton, I hadn't thought of ibid. Yes, I think it should do "ibid., 5:102" if possible. I personally rarely use multicite commands, so for me it doesn't make a difference. But I had no idea it would take so many lines of code! Thank you so much for making it work!

Comment: Most of the code in my answer is to do with deciding when a `shorthand` will be printed based on `biblatex-chicago`'s options. Hooking that code into `\volcite` was straight forward. But hooking it into each cite in `\volcites` took me a while to figure out. I feel like there should have been a better way and I've pinged moewe to take a look as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oooo. I did it!

Just don't ask me to explain how it works. It was basically trial and error.

It works with `\volcite`, `\volcites` and the various `ibid` related options.

It just won't work with something like `\volcite{5}[102]{knuth:ct,CCAG:astrology}`, but I think you are better served with using `\volcites` in this kind of case.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{CCAG:astrology,
  Address = {Brussels},
  Date = {1898/1953},
  Editor = {Cumont, Franz},
  Title = {Catalogus codicum astrologorum graecorum},
  Shorthand = {\emph{CCAG}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\volcitedelim}{\addcolon}
\newcommand*{\volcitepostnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewrobustcmd*{\mkvolcitenote}[2]{%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {\printtext[volcitevolume]{#1}}
    {\printtext{#1}\volcitedelim\printtext{#2}}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{blx@use@volcitepostnotedelim}

\newrobustcmd*{\blx@setvolcitepostnotedelim}{%
  \renewcommand*{\volcitepostnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {}
    {\iftoggle{cms@shorthandibid}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {}
          {\ifboolexpr{
             not togl {cms@firstshort}
             and
             not test {\ifciteseen}
           }
             {}
             {\renewcommand*{\volcitepostnotedelim}{\addspace}}}}
       {\ifboolexpr{
         not togl {cms@firstshort}
         and
         not test {\ifciteseen}
        }
          {}
          {\renewcommand*{\volcitepostnotedelim}{\addspace}}}}%
  \iftoggle{blx@use@volcitepostnotedelim}
    {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\volcitepostnotedelim}}
    {}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\volcitecmd}{%
  \AtNextCite{\DeclareFieldAlias{postnote}{volcitenote}}%
  \AtNextCitekey{\blx@setvolcitepostnotedelim}%
  \begingroup\let\blx@citeargs\blx@volciteargs}

\long\def\blx@volciteargs@i#1[#2]#3{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\toggletrue{blx@use@volcitepostnotedelim}%
     \eappto\blx@tempe{\toggletrue{blx@use@volcitepostnotedelim}}%
     \blx@volciteargs@ii{#1}{#2}{#3}}
    {\togglefalse{blx@use@volcitepostnotedelim}%
     \eappto\blx@tempe{\togglefalse{blx@use@volcitepostnotedelim}}%
     \blx@citeargs@iii{#1{#2}{{#3}{}}}}}

\protected\def\blx@volmciteargs#1{%
  \eappto\blx@tempe{\AtNextCitekey{\blx@setvolcitepostnotedelim}}%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@volciteargs@i{#1}}
    {\blx@volciteargs@i{#1}[]}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\volcite{1}[50]{knuth:ct}.\mancite

\volcite{1--2}{knuth:ct}.

\volcite{5}[102]{CCAG:astrology}.

\volcite{5}[103]{CCAG:astrology}.

\volcite{5}{CCAG:astrology}.

\volcites{1}[50]{knuth:ct}{5}[102]{CCAG:astrology}.

\volcites{5}[102]{CCAG:astrology}{1}[50]{knuth:ct}.

\volcites{1}{knuth:ct}{5}{CCAG:astrology}.

\volcites{5}{CCAG:astrology}{1}{knuth:ct}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Ignoring the question of detecting whether or not the shorthand is present and actively used, the main tasks were to get `\volcite` to use `\volcitepostnotedelim` instead of the normal `\postnotedelim` (or more or less equivalently, to detect that we are in a `\volcite` and use a different definition for `\postnotedelim`) and to detect whether there was an additional page reference. As far as I can see there is nothing present already that would give you that, so I guess low-level redefinitions of `\volcitecmd` and friends are your only chance. ...

Comment: ... It would be nice if that could be avoided. But I'm not entirely sure what exactly would be useful here (one or two (!) new delimiters?, a few tests to check the status of volcite and volcite's postnote?). Maybe you can open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues to discuss this.

Comment: Issue opened at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/868