# Biblatex: How to tweak \volcite to remove comma and "vol." if cited work has a shorthand

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using biblatex with the authoryear-ibid style for inline citation, so somewhat close to the Harvard citation style. I could alternatively use the philosophy-classic or -modern style for the same goal (though I don't know whether they also do ibid, which I'd like)

The problem: I have a mvbook with a shorthand that I'd like to quote. When quoting that, I want the output to omit the comma and the "vol.", so it should look like this:

```
EXP 3, p. 5
```

Meanwhile, without tweaking, the output looks like this:

```
EXP, vol. 3, p.5
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{example.bib}
@mvbook{exampl,
    date = {2000},
    author = {Examplus, Iannus},
    title = {Lorem Ipsum},
    shorthand = {EXP}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
\volcite{2}[5]{exampl}
\end{document}
```

The related questions on here are unfortunately using biblatex-chicago and their solutions seem to include some stuff that the styles I'd use don't provide and I haven't been able to find out how to adapt those to my case.

Comment: This will get easier when `biblatex 3.13` is released. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/868 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472242/87678. I'll see if I can adapt things for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, taken mostly from https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/868.

Much of the code won't be needed once `biblatex 3.13` is released. But is still required for `biblatex 3.12`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{exampl,
    date = {2000},
    author = {Examplus, Iannus},
    title = {Lorem Ipsum},
    shorthand = {EXP}
}
@mvbook{test,
  date = {2019},
  author = {Author, An},
  title = {Some Title}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Work arounds not needed from biblatex 3.13
\makeatletter
\newtoggle{blx@volcite}
\protected\def\ifvolcite{%
  \iftoggle{blx@volcite}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{postnotedelim}}%
     \printfield{postnote}}}
\renewrobustcmd*{\volcitecmd}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{postnote}{volcitenote}%
    \toggletrue{blx@volcite}}%
  \begingroup\let\blx@citeargs\blx@volciteargs}
\long\def\blx@volciteargs@i#1[#2]#3{%
  \def\abx@field@volcitevolume{#3}%
  \undef\abx@field@volcitepages
  \eappto\blx@tempe{%
    \def\noexpand\abx@field@volcitevolume{#3}%
    \undef\noexpand\abx@field@volcitepages}%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@volciteargs@ii{#1}{#2}{#3}}
    {\blx@citeargs@iii{#1{#2}{{#3}{}}}}}
\long\def\blx@volciteargs@ii#1#2#3[#4]{%
  \def\abx@field@volcitepages{#4}%
  \eappto\blx@tempe{\def\noexpand\abx@field@volcitepages{#4}}%
  \blx@citeargs@iii{#1{#2}{{#3}{#4}}}}
\renewrobustcmd*{\multivolcitecmd}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{postnote}{volcitenote}%
    \toggletrue{blx@volcite}}%
  \def\blx@hook@mcite@before{%
    \global\undef\blx@hook@mcite@before
    \let\blx@citeargs\blx@volmciteargs}}
\makeatother


% user level changes

\DeclareDelimFormat[shorthandvolcite]{postnotedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitevolume}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\bibstring{volume}\ppspace#1}
    {#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \ifvolcite
    {\delimcontext{shorthandvolcite}}
    {}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\volcite{2}[5]{exampl}

\volcite{2}{exampl}

\cite[5]{exampl}

\volcite{2}[5]{test}

\volcite{2}{test}

\cite[5]{test}

\volcites{2}[5]{exampl}{2}[5]{test}

\volcites{2}{exampl}{2}{test}

\cites[5]{exampl}[5]{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you a lot, this has done the trick for me!