# Is there a volcite version of notecite in biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I would like to have `biblatex-chicago` automatically format the volume and page numbers of a reference to a multivolume work but without printing anything else. In other words, I want a version of the `\notecite` command for multivolume works. If in fact this does not yet exist, it could be dubbed "`\notevolcite`".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\notecite[22]{knuth:ct}
\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to change `\notecite[22]{knuth:ct}` to `\notevolcite{3}[22]{knuth:ct}` to produce the output:

> vol. 3, p. 22

or, when using [the abbreviated colon formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472053/how-to-tweak-volcite-in-biblatex-chicago-to-cite-volume-and-page-using-arabic-n):

> 3:22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a `\volcite` version of every `\cite...`-like command defined with `\DeclareCiteCommand` by prefixing it with `\volcitecmd`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newrobustcmd*{\notevolcite}{\volcitecmd\notecite}
\newrobustcmd*{\Notevolcite}{\volcitecmd\Notecite}

\begin{document}
\cite[22]{knuth:ct}

\notecite[22]{knuth:ct}

\volcite{3}[22]{knuth:ct}

\notevolcite{3}[22]{knuth:ct}
\end{document}
```

[image: Donald E. Knuth, Computers & Typesetting, 5 vols. (Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1984–1986), 22//22//ibid., vol. 3, p. 22//vol. 3, p. 22]

Multicite commands (those ending in **`s`**, e.g. `\cites`, `\parencites`, ...) can be turned into a `\volcite` command with `\multivolcitecmd`. This is not shown in the MWE because there is no `\notevolcites` (after all, that command would probably create more confusion than clarity).

Comment: Thank you! Now that you answered the question, I realize this syntax looks familiar; I should have been able to come up with it based on your answers to earlier queries. Thank you for your patience. Hopefully I will finally learn this syntax for the future!